# How to implement Freshchat Widget in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I have an Angular 5 based Web App. I am required to Implement Freshchat Widget in it. But the problem is their documentation has only Vanilla JavaScript Implementation, No Documentation for Angular based Web App.

From their documentation at https://developers.freshchat.com/

I need to add the widget for Annonymous User on Landing Page and Once User is logged in the widget should have the Users' Last Conversation so that user can resume his/her query.

The Sample Code shown at https://developers.freshchat.com/#restore-user
to resume user's conversation is very confusing as we are supposed to fetch restoreId before calling the init() method which i don't think we can if we call the init method right before closing body tag in index.html file as per their documentation.

Please help me out here, how do i implement this chat widget in my angular app?

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I am at the same position. Did you solve it?

Comment: @TzviGregoryKaidanov I hade chat with their support team, they have raised a support ticket and will reply via email. Hopefully, they provide any solution soon.

Answer (score 1):

@Sushmit @Tzvi Gregory Kaidanov You can create service like below code and add the `widget.js` in your `index.hmtl` header tag

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FreshchatService {
  init(){
    (<any>window).fcWidget.init({ token:'####-####-######', host : 'DOMAIN_URL'});
  }
}
```

And call that using `freshchatService.init()`